# scala: what is the most elegant way to convert a list of Tries to a Try of list?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a List of tries in scala, for example: List(Try(a), Try(b), Try(c)).
If want to write a code snippets that returns Success(List(a, b, c)) if all tries are successes, and returns a Failure if one of the tries is a failure.

The only way I found to do it is:

```
private def convertArrayOfSuccessesToSuccessOfByteArray(
      tryArrayForOutput: Array[Try[Byte]]
  ): Success[Array[Byte]] = {
    val outputArray = ArrayBuffer[Byte]()
    tryArrayForOutput.foreach(tryElem => {
      val Success(elem) = tryElem
      outputArray.append(elem)
    })
    Success(outputArray.toArray)
  }
```

As you can see, it's pretty cumbersome and not so "functional".

Answer (score 1):

Just `get` each value and wrap in a `Try` to catch the first error, if any

```
Try(tryArrayForOutput.map(_.get))
```

Comment: It can definitely work, but in many places calling "get" on a Try object is considered a bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

@Tim's answer is good in this case.

One more general functional way would be to `fold` and `flatMap`:

```scala
private def convertArrayOfSuccessesToSuccessOfByteArray(tryArrayForOutput: Seq[Try[Byte]]): Try[Seq[Byte]] = {
    tryArrayForOutput.foldLeft(Try(Seq[Byte]())) { (acc: Try[Seq[Byte]], t: Try[Byte]) =>
      acc.flatMap { seq: Seq[Byte] =>
        t.map((b: Byte) => seq :+ b)
      }
    }
  }
```

This can be generalised and is typically a method provided by libraries like Cats.